# How to add cmd-shift-<NUMBER> shortcut to Xcode

Tags: xcode, cmd, keyboard-shortcuts

I tried to add a shortcut (`CMD-Shift-3`) as shortcut for the "Projects" window in Xcode. But when I try to do this via `Preferences->Key Bindings`, I can't realise this. Because it's interpreted as `CMD-#` (with EN/US keyboard layout, or `CMD-§` with DE layout). To make it even worse, I accidentally changed the "Devices" shortcut (trying to copy it). And as there is no "reset to default" on a single shortcut, it's lost.

I can't believe this is actually behaviour implemented by Apple.

Details:
OS X 10.10.3
Xcode 6.3.2

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also want to set this type of shortcut.